# Build Acumatica project getting error: The type or namespace name 'PX' could not be found

Tags: acumatica

I'm learning Acumatica ERP follow course T100_AcumaticaFrameworkIntro_5_0. I can add new class in project and using PX object. But when i build my project i geting error :

Error 1 The type or namespace name 'PX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 2 The type or namespace name 'PXGraph' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[Error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZUyz.png)

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the PX.Data, PX.Common, & PX.objects files (located in your ERP's bin folder) to your custom project.

Comment: sorry ! I was added reference from located in my ERP's bin folder, but i cannot build my project again.

Comment: Make sure you have a "using PX.Data" line at the top of your code file.  You can right-click the error and try to use the "Resolve" functionality to add these using statements as well.

Comment: yes, i have . I don't know why , you can previous my Error capture above

Comment: Ok, I would go to your Project properties and click on the 'Application' tab.  Make sure your target framework is .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: I solved . it's required .NET Framework 4.5.1. Thank you so much !